# I'm getting few error message in Unity with my c# code

Tags: c#, c, .net, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

so I'm creating a simple 2D game in unity and at some point, I'm getting a few errors I think it's because I'm using an old way of writing so if someone can give me a modern way of writing the C# code it will help me very much

Here is the code :

```
    using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed;

    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float horizontalMovement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        MovePlayer(horizontalMovement);
    }

    void MovePlayer(float _horizontalMovement)
    {
        Vector3 targetVelocity = new Vector2(_horizontalMovement, rb.velocity.y);
        rb.velocity = Vector3.SmoothDamp(rb.velocity, targetVelocity, ref velocity, .05f);
    }
}
```

And here are the errors :

> Error detecting Visual Studio installations: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): ApplicationName='C:\Users\Developers Institute\Tom's Adventure\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ide.visualstudio@2.0.12\Editor\VSWhere\vswhere.exe', CommandLine='-prerelease -format json -utf8', CurrentDirectory='', Native error= The system cannot find the file specified.

> UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
> Microsoft.Unity.VisualStudio.Editor.VisualStudioEditor:DiscoverInstallations () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ide.visualstudio@2.0.12/Editor/VisualStudioEditor.cs:59)
> Microsoft.Unity.VisualStudio.Editor.AsyncOperation`1<Microsoft.Unity.VisualStudio.Editor.IVisualStudioInstallation[]>:b__6_0 (object) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ide.visualstudio@2.0.12/Editor/AsyncOperation.cs:38)
> System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback:PerformWaitCallback ()

> Error while executing command: C:\Users\Developers Institute\Tom's Adventure\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.burst@1.6.0.Runtime\hostwin\lld -flavor link /dll /DEBUG /pdb:"C:\Users\Developers Institute\Tom's Adventure\Temp\Burst\burst-aotgjyrtly5.re9\634edd43564d5aeb45f9bce68c886425.pdb" /pdbaltpath:"C:\Users\Developers Institute\Tom's Adventure\Library\BurstCache\JIT\634edd43564d5aeb45f9bce68c886425.pdb" /noentry /nodefaultlib /out:"C:\Users\Developers Institute\Tom's Adventure\Temp\Burst\burst-aotgjyrtly5.re9\634edd43564d5aeb45f9bce68c886425.dll" "C:\Users\Developers Institute\Tom's Adventure\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.burst@1.6.0\.Runtime\libs\burstRTL_w64.lib" /threads:1 "C:\Users\Developers Institute\Tom's Adventure\Temp\Burst\burst-aotgjyrtly5.re9\lib_burst_generated_part_.obj"

> While compiling job: System.Void Unity.Burst.Intrinsics.X86::DoSetCSRTrampoline(System.Int32)
> at :line 0

> Unexpected exception Burst.Compiler.IL.Aot.AotLinkerException: The native link step failed Error while executing command: C:\Users\Developers Institute\Tom's Adventure\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.burst@1.6.0.Runtime\hostwin\lld -flavor link /dll /DEBUG /pdb:"C:\Users\Developers Institute\Tom's Adventure\Temp\Burst\burst-aotgjyrtly5.re9\634edd43564d5aeb45f9bce68c886425.pdb" /pdbaltpath:"C:\Users\Developers Institute\Tom's Adventure\Library\BurstCache\JIT\634edd43564d5aeb45f9bce68c886425.pdb" /noentry /nodefaultlib /out:"C:\Users\Developers Institute\Tom's Adventure\Temp\Burst\burst-aotgjyrtly5.re9\634edd43564d5aeb45f9bce68c886425.dll" "C:\Users\Developers Institute\Tom's Adventure\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.burst@1.6.0\.Runtime\libs\burstRTL_w64.lib" /threads:1 "C:\Users\Developers Institute\Tom's Adventure\Temp\Burst\burst-aotgjyrtly5.re9\lib_burst_generated_part_.obj". Check previous exception in the log - linker command line : "C:\Users\Developers Institute\Tom's Adventure\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.burst@1.6.0.Runtime\hostwin\lld -flavor link /dll /DEBUG /pdb:"C:\Users\Developers Institute\Tom's Adventure\Temp\Burst\burst-aotgjyrtly5.re9\634edd43564d5aeb45f9bce68c886425.pdb" /pdbaltpath:"C:\Users\Developers Institute\Tom's Adventure\Library\BurstCache\JIT\634edd43564d5aeb45f9bce68c886425.pdb" /noentry /nodefaultlib /out:"C:\Users\Developers Institute\Tom's Adventure\Temp\Burst\burst-aotgjyrtly5.re9\634edd43564d5aeb45f9bce68c886425.dll" "C:\Users\Developers Institute\Tom's Adventure\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.burst@1.6.0\.Runtime\libs\burstRTL_w64.lib" /threads:1 "C:\Users\Developers Institute\Tom's Adventure\Temp\Burst\burst-aotgjyrtly5.re9\lib_burst_generated_part_.obj""
> at Burst.Compiler.IL.Aot.AotNativeLinkBase.RunNativeLinkerTool (System.String command, System.String arguments, System.String errorMessage, System.String commandType, System.String workingDirectory, System.Boolean muteOutputs) [0x0008b] in <685f0c65f2a448a78ba2734aa17d6be3>:0
> at Burst.Compiler.IL.Aot.AotNativeLinkLLVMWindows.Link (Burst.Backend.TargetCpu targetCpu, System.Collections.Generic.List'1[T] inputFiles, System.String outputFile, System.Boolean enableDebugInfo) [0x001b0] in <685f0c65f2a448a78ba2734aa17d6be3>:0
> at Burst.Compiler.IL.Aot.AotCompiler.Link (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] groups, System.String nameSuffix, Burst.Compiler.IL.Aot.AotCompilerOptions compilerOptions, System.IO.TextWriter consoleOut, System.IO.TextWriter consoleError) [0x001f8] in <685f0c65f2a448a78ba2734aa17d6be3>:0
> at Burst.Compiler.IL.Jit.Providers.BaseOnDiskProvider.CommonDiskCompileModule (Burst.Backend.Module module, Burst.Compiler.IL.NativeCompiler nativeCompiler, Burst.Compiler.IL.NativeCompilerOptions options, Burst.Compiler.IL.Jit.JitOptions jitOptions, Burst.Compiler.IL.Helpers.Hash128& moduleHash) [0x000b2] in <685f0c65f2a448a78ba2734aa17d6be3>:0
> at Burst.Compiler.IL.Jit.Providers.OnDiskJitProvider.BeginCompileModule (Burst.Backend.Module module, Burst.Compiler.IL.NativeCompiler nativeCompiler, Burst.Compiler.IL.NativeCompilerOptions options, Burst.Compiler.IL.Jit.JitOptions jitOptions, Burst.Compiler.IL.Helpers.Hash128& moduleHash, Burst.Compiler.IL.Jit.JitCacheManager jitCacheManager, Burst.Compiler.IL.Jit.GetExternalFunctionPointerDelegate getExternalFunctionPointer, System.Action& invokeBurstInitialize) [0x00000] in <685f0c65f2a448a78ba2734aa17d6be3>:0
> at Burst.Compiler.IL.Jit.JitCompiler.CompileMethodInternal (Burst.Compiler.IL.Jit.JitResult result, System.Collections.Generic.List'1[T] methodsToCompile, Burst.Compiler.IL.Jit.JitOptions jitOptions) [0x00677] in <685f0c65f2a448a78ba2734aa17d6be3>:0
> at Burst.Compiler.IL.Jit.JitCompiler.CompileMethods (Burst.Compiler.IL.Jit.JitMethodGroupRequest& request, Burst.Compiler.IL.Jit.JitCompilationRequestType requestType) [0x00209] in <685f0c65f2a448a78ba2734aa17d6be3>:0
> at Burst.Compiler.IL.Jit.JitCompiler.CompileMethod (Burst.Compiler.IL.Jit.MethodReferenceWithMethodRefString method, Burst.Compiler.IL.Jit.JitOptions jitOptions, Burst.Compiler.IL.Jit.JitCompilationRequestType requestType) [0x00023] in <685f0c65f2a448a78ba2734aa17d6be3>:0
> at Burst.Compiler.IL.Jit.JitCompilerService+CompilerThreadContext.Compile (Burst.Compiler.IL.Jit.JitCompilerService+CompileJob job, Burst.Compiler.IL.Jit.JitCompilationRequestType requestType) [0x00491] in <685f0c65f2a448a78ba2734aa17d6be3>:0

> While compiling job: System.Void Unity.Burst.Intrinsics.X86::DoSetCSRTrampoline(System.Int32)
> at :line 0

Yeah I know it's a lot sorry about that I'm still a beginner

Comment: I am not exactly sure what all of the other errors mean, but they could be dependent on the first error. In it it says that it was unable to access a file called ```vswhere.exe```. If you could go to this file path and see if you have it: ```C:\Users\Developers Institute\Tom's Adventure\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ide.visualstudio@2.0.12\Editor\VSWhere\```

Comment: These errors seem to be in no way related to anything in the code you shared ... Are these compile time or runtime errors?

Answer (score 3):

Try going to Edit>Preferences>External Tools> Set your External Script editor to the correct version of vs, and then click "Regenerate project Files" button.

I see errors like this in my projects from time to time, and this almost always seems to fix it.

Comment: okay I'll do that, thank you very much