# Error detecting Visual Studio installations Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I installed Vscode for Unity but then, when I do some coding and imported it to unity, this shows up:

```
    Error detecting Visual Studio installations: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): ApplicationName='D:\FindersKeepers\Thanatos's punishment\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ide.visualstudio@2.0.14\Editor\VSWhere\vswhere.exe', CommandLine='-prerelease -format json -utf8', CurrentDirectory='', Native error= The system cannot find the file specified.

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
Microsoft.Unity.VisualStudio.Editor.VisualStudioEditor:DiscoverInstallations () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ide.visualstudio@2.0.14/Editor/VisualStudioEditor.cs:59)
Microsoft.Unity.VisualStudio.Editor.AsyncOperation`1<Microsoft.Unity.VisualStudio.Editor.IVisualStudioInstallation[]>:<Run>b__6_0 (object) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ide.visualstudio@2.0.14/Editor/AsyncOperation.cs:38)
System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback:PerformWaitCallback ()
```

Do I have to install something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the tips suggested here:
[I'm getting few error message in Unity with my c# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70577854/im-getting-few-error-message-in-unity-with-my-c-sharp-code/70584036#70584036)

> Try going to Edit > Settings > External Tools> Install the correct vs
> version for your external script editor, and then click the "Restore
> Project Files" button.

And here:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/error-detecting-visual-studio-installations.902792/

> Open the Package Manager in Unity and find the "Visual Studio Code"
> package that is installed in your project. Update it to the new
> version

Comment: @Yunnosch thanks for the comment, corrected the answer :)

Comment: You phrase "Try". Dou think this is a solution or do you ask whether it helps? The latter would have to be a comment (again, no privilege yet...)